# Using exceljs node package create xlsx file

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, npm, exceljs

I am using exceljs 3.8 to create new xlsx file but some reason below code not working ?

```
     createNewExcelFile:  function (excelFilePath) {
           //excelFilePath: Provide path and file name for excel file
           // load exceljs module
           var workbook = new exceljs.Workbook(); //create object of workbook
           //add sheet to workbook
           var newSheet = workbook.addWorksheet('TestData');
           //use write file function to create new file
           workbook.xlsx.writeBuffer(excelFilePath) 
               .then(function () {
                   console.log("excel file created successfully");
               });
       }

createNewExcelFile('new1.xlsx');
```

console.log is logging "**excel file created successfully**" but i don't see any where file getting created.

Answer (score 2):

### 1. You should use `writeFile` instead of `writeBuffer`

```
workbook.xlsx.writeFile(excelFilePath);
```

(Source: https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs#writing-xlsx)

### 2. `xlsx-renderer`

I would also recommend using `xlsx-renderer` which provides generating excel files based on Template and ViewModel.

Template + ViewModel = Preaty XLSX

**Template:**
[image: Template file]

**VM:**

```
{
"projects": [
    {
        "name": "ExcelJS",
        "role": "maintainer",
        "platform": "github",
        "link": "https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs",
        "stars": 5300,
        "forks": 682
    },
    {
        "name": "xlsx-import",
        "role": "owner",
        "platform": "github",
        "link": "https://github.com/siemienik/xlsx-import",
...
```

**Gives:**
[image]

This library will work great with your code because it based on ExcelJs too.

(Source: https://github.com/Siemienik/xlsx-renderer/tree/master/tests/integration/data/Renderer009-ForEach-Average)

**EDIT: (29.04.2020)**
In the practice it's used by the following code:

```
const result = await renderer.renderFromFile('./report-template.xlsx', { awesome:"Oh yeah!", items:[/*...*/]});
await result.xlsx.writeFile('./my-awesome-report.xlsx');
```

Comment: So you mean this library automatically create file and add data into it..no need to create any empty excel also ?

Comment: Yeah, it uses the template that was prepared before. And put data into a cell with value started by `##`. It has the possibility to looping / inserting hyperlinks and many more.

It's really fine because allow easily change the template without any code changes. For example, always when a company change visual identification.

I've added also into the post above code how to use it.

It's will be available as a restful microservice under docker soon.